# Glass Throwing Error

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

I have some questions regarding my block of code. I've tried running it in Netbeans and it doesn't seem to like this block of code on Google Glass. I compiled it using Eclipse and it seems to compile correctly as well.

```
package com.openglassquartz.helloglass;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class OnlineRetrieval {

boolean activeGame;

public boolean checkGame() { //Method for which to check if there is a current game going on.

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://danielchan.me/league/active.txt");
        Scanner s = new Scanner(url.openStream()); //All errors point to this line of code??
        int temporary_Reading = s.nextInt();

        if(temporary_Reading == 1) {
            return activeGame = true;
        } else {
            return activeGame = false;
        }
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    return activeGame;
}
  }
```

From the LaunchService Class.

```
OnlineRetrieval OR = new OnlineRetrieval();
boolean temp_Check = OR.checkGame();
```

```
01-14 16:38:32.187: E/AndroidRuntime(18639):    at com.openglassquartz.helloglass.OnlineRetrieval.checkGame(OnlineRetrieval.java:20)
01-14 16:38:32.187: E/AndroidRuntime(18639):    at com.openglassquartz.helloglass.CardLaunchService.onStartCommand(CardLaunchService.java:77)
```

How can I fix this? It seems to work on Netbeans when I tried outputting it but not in Google Glass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to look at (it looks like your stack trace is cut off in your post):

1. Did you add the `android.permission.INTERNET` permission to your application's manifest?
2. Is this code being called in the main UI thread? Network operations *must* be executed in a background thread – you may want to look at the [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) class as a way of handling this.

Comment: Yeah I saw my mistake. Seems like I have quite abit of reading to do haha. Many thanks!